# Error inflating class B

Tags: android, class, apk, signed

I´ve a weird problem when building my signed App via AndroidStudio.

The app is generated successful, but when I want to start it on my smartphone I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.package, PID: 21935
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package/gui.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.perfor

mLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class Button
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.ae.a()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.ag.setBackgroundDrawable(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:19498)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4932)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1041)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:113)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ag.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ag.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.au.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.a.af.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.g.ad.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.onCreateView(PreferenceFragment.java:179)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2352)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1582)
    at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:372)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6971)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

When I start the app via Debug mode or build a debug APK file, it starts normally.

I see that there is a problem with a button in one Binary XML file in line #58.
But in which file? In the Main class there is only a preference file without any button...

And why does it work in Debug mode?

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because you have enabled proguard in signed version.

Comment: You need to provide more details . Provide code and indicate whats on `Line #58` . Also indicate if you are using proguard .

Comment: Yes I use proguard, but only with "-ignorewarnings".

Answer (score 0):

When I disable proguard it works! :-)

But what is the problem with proguard?

Here is my Grandle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
    }
```

}

proguard.cfg:

```
-ignorewarnings
```